# how to slide out content on hover - flexbox-layout

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, twitter-bootstrap, flexbox

i have a beautiful little landing page with big pictures and small boxes with headings in it.

if you hover over the headings, the box around it should slide out (getting more width but shouldn't push the picture away, instead it should be above the picture) the picture next to it and shows some text there. this is all done in a flexbox-bootstrap layout.

will `position: absolute`, `z-index` and some `left` or `right` stuff do this trick as well even in a flexbox-content? or do i have to use some jscript/jQuery stuff?

here's my bootply: http://www.bootply.com/d2liwNZnCH

and the code for the greater good:

```
<main class="container">
                <div class="row row-flex row-flex-wrap">
                    <div class="col-md-3 bgb fw">
                        <div class="contentbox flex-col">
                            <h2>example</h2>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                    <div class="col-md-3">
                        <div class="imagecontainer">
                          <img src="http://placehold.it/365x365" alt="Beispielinhalt" class="img-responsive">
                        </div>
                    </div>
                    <div class="col-md-3">
                        <div class="imagecontainer">
                            <img src="http://placehold.it/365x365" alt="Beispielinhalt" class="img-responsive">
                        </div>
                    </div>
                    <div class="col-md-3 bgr fw">
                        <div class="contentbox flex-col">
                            <h2>example</h2>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div>
                <div class="row row-flex row-flex-wrap">
                    <div class="col-md-8">
                        <div class="imagecontainer">
                            <img src="http://placehold.it/1265x365" alt="Beispielinhalt" class="img-responsive">
                        </div>
                    </div>
                    <div class="col-md-4 bgp fw">
                        <div class="contentbox flex-col">
                            <h2>example</h2>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div>
                <div class="row row-flex row-flex-wrap">
                    <div class="col-md-5 bgg fw">
                        <div class="contentbox flex-col">
                            <h2>example</h2>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                    <div class="col-md-7">
                        <div class="imagecontainer">
                            <img src="http://placehold.it/765x365" alt="Beispielinhalt" class="img-responsive">
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </main> <!-- Maincontent -->
```

css:

```
.col-xs-1, .col-sm-1, .col-md-1, .col-lg-1, .col-xs-2, .col-sm-2, .col-md-2, .col-lg-2, .col-xs-3, .col-sm-3, .col-md-3, .col-lg-3, .col-xs-4, .col-sm-4, .col-md-4, .col-lg-4, .col-xs-5, .col-sm-5, .col-md-5, .col-lg-5, .col-xs-6, .col-sm-6, .col-md-6, .col-lg-6, .col-xs-7, .col-sm-7, .col-md-7, .col-lg-7, .col-xs-8, .col-sm-8, .col-md-8, .col-lg-8, .col-xs-9, .col-sm-9, .col-md-9, .col-lg-9, .col-xs-10, .col-sm-10, .col-md-10, .col-lg-10, .col-xs-11, .col-sm-11, .col-md-11, .col-lg-11, .col-xs-12, .col-sm-12, .col-md-12, .col-lg-12 {
        margin: 0;
        padding: 0;
    }
    .row-flex, .row-flex > div[class*='col-'] {  
        display: -webkit-box;
        display: -moz-box;
        display: -ms-flexbox;
        display: -webkit-flex;
        display: flex;
        flex:1 1 auto;
    }

    .row-flex-wrap {
        -webkit-flex-flow: row wrap;
        align-content: flex-start;
        flex:0;
    }

    .row-flex > div[class*='col-'], .container-flex > div[class*='col-'] {
         margin:-.2px; /* hack adjust for wrapping */
    }

    .container-flex > div[class*='col-'] div,.row-flex > div[class*='col-'] div {
        width:100%;
    }


    .flex-col {
        display: flex !important;
        display: -webkit-flex !important;
        flex: 1 100%;
        flex-flow: column nowrap;
        align-items: center;
        justify-content: center;
    }

    .flex-grow {
        display: flex;
        -webkit-flex: 2;
        flex: 2;
    }
    h1, h2, h3, h4, h5, h6 {
        margin-top: 0px;
        word-break: break-word;
    }
    .contentbox {
        padding: 15px 30px 15px 30px;
        text-align: center;
        display: block;
    }
    .contentbox h2 {
        font-variant: small-caps;
    }
    .imagecontainer {
        display: block;
    }
```

Comment: Questions seeking code help must include the shortest code necessary to reproduce it **in the question itself**.   Although you have provided a link to an example, if the link were to become invalid, your question would be of no value to other future SO users with the same problem.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

did it with a second ".contentbox"-div and some helper classes and jQuery click event and i chosed to fade the readmore-text in the contentbox itself above the centered heading.

html:

```
<div class="col-lg-3 col-sm-6 col-xs-12 fw">
                        <div class="contentbox readmore bgr flex-col">
                            <h2>example</h2>
                        </div>
                        <div class="contentbox expand bgr flex-col">
                            <span aria-hidden="true" class="pull-right closebox">&times;</span>
                            <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consetetur sadipscing elitr, sed diam nonumy eirmod tempor invidunt ut labore et dolore magna aliquyam erat, sed diam voluptua. At vero eos et accusam et justo duo dolores et ea rebum. Stet clita kasd gubergren, no sea takimata.</p>
                            <p><a href="#" class="btn btn-default">read more</a></p>
                        </div>
                    </div>
```

css:

```
.contentbox {
        padding: 15px 30px 15px 30px;
        text-align: center;
        display: block;
        height: auto;
        min-height: 160px; /* Only for my layout */
    }
    .readmore {
        cursor: pointer; /* So your complete box seems clickable */
    }
.expand {
        position: absolute;
        top: 0; /* You can switch these values to whatever values wished */
        left: 0; /* It will then slide from the direction you chose */
        right: 0; /* but remember to put the chosen direction to 0 again on .expanded */
        bottom: 0; /* for me, the fadeeffect was the most elegant way */
        font-size: 15px;
        opacity: 0;
        visibility: hidden;
        transition: all .75s ease-in-out;
    }
    .expanded {
        top: 0;
        opacity: 1;
        visibility: visible;
        cursor: default;
        transition: all .75s ease-in-out;
    }
    .closebox {
        font-size: 24px;
        position: absolute;
        right: 10px;
        top: 0px;
        cursor: pointer;
    }
```

js within document ready:

```
$(".readmore").click(function(){
        $(this).next(".expand").addClass("expanded");
    });
    $(".closebox").click(function(){
       $(this).parent(".expanded").removeClass("expanded"); 
    });
```